# PHP - POST Method - What happens when content exceeds content length header?

Tags: php, html, apache, cgi

I don't mean the POST content limit imposed by php.ini, I mean in the request header the content length is set as say 1mb, but 2mb of actual content is sent.

Comment: that is going to be behavior that is dependant on what web server you running. I believe the appropriate response is a 413 Entity Too Large

Answer (score 0):

1 - The first 1mb does not get passed to the PHP file immediately once received the whole data get passed to php file.

2 - The additional data and the previous data does not passed to PHP file.